Flink deployment failed to spin up the new app due to savepoint not exists
I use flink operator 1.6.1 to deploy my  flink app (v1.14.5). I've configured the app with the follow job settings:
job:
    allowNonRestoredState: true
    args:
    - <command to run my job>
    entryClass: org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkPortableClientEntryPoint
    jarURI: local:///opt/flink/flink-web-upload/beam-runner.jar
    parallelism: 32
    state: running
    upgradeMode: last-state

and here's my flinkConfiguration:
flinkConfiguration:
    fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider: com.amazonaws.auth.WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider
    high-availability: org.apache.flink.kubernetes.highavailability.KubernetesHaServicesFactory
    high-availability.storageDir: s3://<path>/high-availability
    state.backend: rocksdb
    state.backend.fs.checkpointdir: file:///checkpoints/flink/checkpoints
    state.backend.incremental: "true"
    state.checkpoints.dir: s3a://<path>/checkpoints
    state.savepoints.dir: s3a://<path>/savepoints

But I noticed that sometimes if I want to deploy a new version of code change (usually just new docker image with some internal library change), some of the flinkdeployment app failed with:
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find checkpoint or savepoint file/directory 's3a://<path>/savepoints/savepoint-2254eb-61d7c7a6f6a3' on file
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.AbstractFsCheckpointStorageAccess.resolveCheckpointPointer(AbstractFsCheckpointStorageAccess.java:275)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.AbstractFsCheckpointStorageAccess.resolveCheckpoint(AbstractFsCheckpointStorageAccess.java:136)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointCoordinator.restoreSavepoint(CheckpointCoordinator.java:1639)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultExecutionGraphFactory.tryRestoreExecutionGraphFromSavepoint(DefaultExecutionGraphFactory.java:163)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultExecutionGraphFactory.createAndRestoreExecutionGraph(DefaultExecutionGraphFactory.java:138)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.createAndRestoreExecutionGraph(SchedulerBase.java:335)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.<init>(SchedulerBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.<init>(DefaultScheduler.java:140)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultSchedulerFactory.createInstance(DefaultSchedulerFactory.java:134)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.DefaultSlotPoolServiceSchedulerFactory.createScheduler(DefaultSlotPoolServiceSchedulerFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.createScheduler(JobMaster.java:346)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.<init>(JobMaster.java:323)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.factories.DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.internalCreateJobMasterService(DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.java:106)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.factories.DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.lambda$createJobMasterService$0(DefaultJobMasterServiceFactory.java:94)
    at org.apache.flink.util.function.FunctionUtils.lambda$uncheckedSupplier$4(FunctionUtils.java:112)

Wondering if anyone know how can I fix this issue? Thanks

I've double checked the savepoint doesn't seem to appear in my code.
I wonder how the flink app get this non-exists savepoint folder?  and also is it possible to force it to use the latest checkpoint if it is unable to find the savepoint folder ?


also FYI that we don't have s3 lifecycle configured and i've confirmed no one trying to manually delete things on this checkpoint/savepoint path.

This is probably unrelated, but I don't believe that a setting named state.backend.fs.checkpointdir exists, and if it did, why would you set it, since you are using RocksDB. And why would it have a different value than state.checkpoints.dir?
